# POST URL to be redirected to particular API except for one string which should go to separate URL

Tags: regex, web-services, rest, get, restful-url

I want to have REST API's for two functions, the first one is getting the name of the laptops that have the string '`laptop_re`' in their name and other one is getting details of the screen sizes of the laptops I have

I have made a URL:

```
(r'/v1/laptops/' + laptop_re + '$', 'GET', getAllLaptops)
```

and another URL is:

```
(r'/v1/laptops/validscreensizes', 'GET', getAllValidScreenSizes)
```

The problem here is that when i try to run this API, it  tries to search the laptop with name '`validscreensizes`' and does not hit the 2nd URL. It redirects everything to the first URL.
I can hardcode

```
laptop_re = r'(?!validscreensizes)[a-zA-z0-9_~%\.\-]+'
```

But I don't want to do this. Can anyone suggest what is the best design practice in this case?

Comment: What about putting the most specific case first?

Comment: Yeah that is a pretty good option but that would restrict my laptop name choices to anything other that validscreensizes.

Comment: @The_Lost_Avatar If `validscreensizes` is a valid laptop name, your requirement is ambiguous, and you have a requirement problem, not a technical implementation question. You either need to (a) make it a forbidden laptop name or (b) change your required URL structure.

Comment: So what should be the change in required URL strucure keeping in mind i dont want to compromise with the readability of the API's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider breaking out a new top-level resource to expose what you want.

```
GET /availableResolutions?laptopId=1234
{
    "resolutions": [
        {
            "laptopId": 1234,
            "resolution": "640x480"
        },
        {
            "laptopId": 1234,
            "resolution": "1280x960"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option would be to make the set of available resolutions a sub-resource for a specific laptop:

```
GET /laptops/{laptopId}/availableResolutions
```

Without more information about your API, it's difficult to say which one is more correct.

Comment: I have implemented the "putting the most specific case first comment  " by DUSTMOUSE, but this one is a pretty good option too.